# How to start pg_cron extension after shutdown

Tags: database, postgresql, unix, postgresql-12, postgresql-extensions

Had to terminate a process run by pg_cron. However, after doing that pg_cron extension stopped. Below is the log from the server:

```
2021-04-29 12:55:40.712 UTC [535529] LOG:  pg_cron scheduler shutting down
```

Now, no jobs are running. How to restart the extension without restarting the PostgreSQL server.